# Split and merge/concat recorded audio

Tags: android, android-ndk, aac, mediarecorder, amr

I need to be able to split and merge recorded audio in Android. Since there are [a number](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) of different formats, does anyone know which format is easiest to handle?

It's only the formats with a dot under "Encoder" that is available for recording.

Answer (score 0):

You can record .wav files by capturing the raw audio data by using [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html). You don't need any encoding, just prepend a [small 44-byte header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) and you have your .wav file. Splitting and merging the raw audio data is then trivial, since they are just arrays of values.